# Biblatex journal: issue, number punctuation

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I use biblatex-biber in a report class, and need to modify my journal footnote from this:

> JOUR 24, no. 2 (1998)

to this:

> JOUR 24.2 (1998)

I am using a document style I did not create, and need to know where to place the macros, whether in `cbx` or any other file. The changes involve 1) replacement of comma with period, 2) elimination of "no." and space. In case there is no issue number, the period should be omitted.

Comment: How can we possibly know 'where to place the macros' if you don't give us code? Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Without  knowing the .sty/.cls file, it's hard to say something useful.

Comment: As Volume.Number is the default, you clearly need to show us a minimal example.

Comment: I would gladly provide a MWE but this complex document class given to me does not afford that. Most if not all macros rely on each other across several files. I am thinking on how to provide that.

Comment: The document class itself will in most cases have no bearing on `bibalatex`'s output. You could check if the problem persists, if you use, say, the `article` class. We will, however, not be able to come up with a proper answer without the appropriate information - you haven't even told us the `biblatex` style you use.

Comment: @moewe, I use a custom style derived from the anyt chicago style

Comment: Aha! When you say "anyt", do you mean the normal `biblatex-chicago`/`note` style, perchance?

Comment: @moewe, I am pretty sure, according to the following info I have in my class file: `\RequirePackage[style=sbl,backend=biber,sorting=anyt]{biblatex}`

Comment: Well, the `anyt` just specifies the sorting, it is much more important what the `sbl` file actually is. But the files does not seem to be publicly available, so that line above is not really conclusive - we would need to know the internals of a style file. Please try my answer below. But without knowing what the `.bbx`/`.cbx` files look like giving a proper answer is hard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21377/discussion-between-nhaps-and-moewe).

Comment: @moewe, thanks for your attention, and the accurate solution you provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your style file contains the lines

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield[no]{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

where `no` is defined as `\DeclareFieldFormat{no}{\bibsstring{number}~#1}`.

But we don't want a comma and space after the `volume` and don't care for the number prefix, so we get rid of it

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

---

Since you use a style derived from `biblatex-chicago`'s `notes` style, we will have to redefine its macros. (Indeed the behaviour you seek to achieve is the default behaviour in `biblatex`'s standard styles.)

Since `biblatex-chicago` is specifically designed to exactly mirror the CMS, at times modifications can be quite awkward, as we will see here.

The relevant macros `cjournal+ser+vol+num` and `cperiodical+ser+vol+num` both contain the lines

```
\printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
\setunit*{\adddot}%
\printfield[journum]{number}%
```

which for our purposes need to be

```
\printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
\setunit*{\adddot}%
\printfield{number}%
```

mimicking the standard definition (found in `standard.bbx`) of

```
\newbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

So we need to

```
\renewbibmacro*{cjournal+ser+vol+num}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal+sub}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printlist[periodplace]{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newcunit
      \printfield[jourser]{series}%
      \newcunit}%\setunit*{\addspace}?
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{cperiodical+ser+vol+num}{% For periodical entries,
  \printtext[title]{% article subtype
    \printfield[noformat]{title}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
    \printfield[noformat]{subtitle}}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printlist[periodplace]{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newcunit
      \printfield[jourser]{series}%
      \newcunit}%\setunit*{\addspace}?
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cjournal+ser+vol+num}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal+sub}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printlist[periodplace]{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newcunit
      \printfield[jourser]{series}%
      \newcunit}%\setunit*{\addspace}?
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{cperiodical+ser+vol+num}{% For periodical entries,
  \printtext[title]{% article subtype
    \printfield[noformat]{title}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
    \printfield[noformat]{subtitle}}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printlist[periodplace]{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newcunit
      \printfield[jourser]{series}%
      \newcunit}%\setunit*{\addspace}?
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
\cite{baez/article,bertram,doody}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]